# Thread pool в Java

Tags: многопоточность, java

Добрый день!

пусть у нас есть код:

```
final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
```

при каждом помещение в пул нового потока(который еще не выполняется):

```
es.execute(someRunnable)
```

тот попадает в область **ready-to-run** .В зависимости от приоритета, все входящие потоки выстраиваются в очередь(если приоритеты совпадают, то кто раньше пришел). **ExecutorService** отбирает из них 2 потока и помещает в область **running**, тоесть запускает. Когда хотя бы 1 поток перестает временно работать(заснул, выполнен **yield**), то он отправляется обратно в **ready-to-run**, а на его место другой встает. Если поток прерван, то он навсегда из пула вылетает.

Вопрос такой, в рамках этой модели, для чего в **ThreadPool** нужны 2 сайза : **MaximumPoolSize** и **CorePoolSize**

Answer (score 5):

С терминологией беда. `executor.execute(Runnable)` не помещает никаких потоков ни в какие пулы, а просто помещает вашу **задачу** в очередь.

`corePoolSize` устанавливает кол-во потоков, которые всегда готовы к использованию (если idle), или заняты обработкой задач.

`maximumPoolSize` устанавливает границы увеличения размера пула.

В случае использования `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)` параметры `corePoolSize` и `maximumPoolSize` принимают одинаковые значения.

В этой модели вы как раз не оперируете `maximumPoolSize` отдельно. Но в модели `ThreadPoolExecutor` принимают участие оба этих параметра.

Comment: дада,я  это уже понял) те потоки, которые в данный момент не работают(idle), то они из пула выкидываются в очередь

Comment: @voipp, а в [документации](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) читали?

Я вот сейчас глянул, IMHO там все про стратегию рааботы с разными видами очередей и разными размерами параметров MaximumPoolSize и CorePoolSize очень толково написано.

Comment: Вот и я о том же, что в документации все описано очень хорошо.

Comment: вообще мне очень помогла другая статья, а не доки.
Вот она : http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/11/27/rules-of-a-threadpoolexecutor-pool-size

Comment: @huffman, а я о том, что если бы все не ленились, внимательно читали документацию и тщательно штудировали (с набором собственных "тестов") исходники, то форум просто был бы не востребован.

В лучшем случае раз-другой в месяц кто-нибудь делился бы своими достижениями (скорее всего в важной, но не очень интересной для всех области).

Comment: @avp, я с вами не согласен. Если бы все читали документацию и смотрели исходники то качественных вопросов на форумах было бы больше да и софт разрабатывался бы во-много раз качественнее.

Answer (score 4):

В документации же написано английским по белому:

corePoolSize - the number of threads to keep in the pool, even if they are idle.

maximumPoolSize - the maximum number of threads to allow in the pool.

Comment: Вы молодцы, что можете прочитать по-английски.maximumPoolSize  - имеется ввиду весь пул?(обе области) corePoolSize - размер области **redy-to-run** ?

Comment: ну откройте исходные тексты да посмотрите, религия не позволяет? -)

Comment: там очень много читать, мне лень.

Comment: @huffman, не думали, что вопросы сюда задают еще и для того, чтобы не тратить время на изучение исходников?

Т.е. в надежде, что кто-то его уже потратил и ему не лень быстренько поделиться своими знаниями.

Comment: Я вам дал два важных совета, 1 - читайте документацию, 2 - если что-то не понятно смотрите исходники. Если вам лень то может вам не стоит заниматься программированием?

Comment: ладно ладно, почитаю исходники(

Comment: @voipp а чем вы недовольны собсно говоря? Вам дали нормальный ответ

Answer (score 1):

Я разобрался! сначала все таски кладутся в **corePool**(выполняются в трэде) , когда его размер превышен, то таски начинают класться в **Очередь**, когда и она полна, таски выполняются в трэдах, при этом размер пула возрастает. Если размер пула равен **maximumPoolSize** и при этом полна очередь, то новые таски отклоняются. Нонепонятно, как себя поведет программа, в которой положено столько трэдов в пул. Она кинет исключение?

Comment: Таски всегда кладутся в очередь. Задача executor'а пропагейтить их на выполнение при наличии свободных потоков.

Comment: я понял, просто по дефолту, очередь бесконечно большая. Можно ее ограничить и тогда не будут кластся(условия я написал выше)